# append csv files one by one in numeric order using bash shell script

Tags: shell

Given files named 1.csv, 2.csv, 3.csv, ...89.csv... n.csv
how do I append them together in numeric order)(1 to n) in bash shell script?
is there a one-liner for the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your files where named with leading zeros, it would be easier, i.e.

```
  cat [0-9].csv [0-9][0-9].csv .... > new.csv
```

But its not too hard to get a true numeric order, given

```
ls -1
1
10
11
12
13
2
20
21
3
7
8
9
```

(in both samples, note that the option to ls is the number one, (1), not the letter L (l))

AND

```
ls -1 [0-9]* | sort -n
1
2
3
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
20
21
```

THEN

```
  cat $( ls -1 *.csv | sort -n  ) > new.csv
```

Assuming all your csv files are numbered.

If you have more than 1000 files, file arg processing in the shell may break down, and you should post a new question for correct use of xargs.

To see what is happening add shell debugging/trace use

```
 set -vx  # to turn on
 set +vx  # to turn it off
```

.

IHTH.

Comment: ls -l *.csv|sort -n seems to be out of order:  ls -l *.csv |sort -n
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 110427099 Sep  4 20:37 94.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 110439250 Sep  4 20:15 93.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 111962812 Sep  4 19:53 92.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 114716696 Sep  4 14:35 65.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 115487626 Sep  4 08:05 35.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 115777573 Sep  3 20:25 1.csv

Comment: Note that is -1 (one), not -l (the letter L). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

One liner with inline params (you should replace N with maximal file number). Script will skip unexisted files, so if you miss few files in sequence you wouldn't get error :)

```
for i in `seq 0 N`; do test -f $i.csv && cat $i.csv; done >> result.csv
```

Or script with params

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `seq 0 $1`
do
    if [ -f "$i.csv" ]
    then
        cat $i.csv >> $2
    fi
done
```

Usage: ./script.sh MAX_CSV_ID RESULT_FILE

Example: ./script.sh 89 new.csv